# Object tree traversal in ruby

Tags: ruby

So... I have the following:

A class with several properties which are retrieved from an .xml file. These properties are if the object is a condition (it has two children) and its name. Basically, the object's children properties are the names of its children.

The .xml looks like this:

```
<object-2>
     <name>Object - 2</name>
     <yesChild>Object - 3</yesChild>
     <noChild>Object - 4</noChild>
</object-2>
```

If the noChild is empty, then it means that the object is not a condition. All objects retrieved from the .xml are stored into an array.

What I need is to somehow create a tree out of it and identify all paths that can be taken in order to reach the last element in the array. The algorithm does not need to traverse all nodes, just the ones it needs to reach the last element of the array.

Example:

We have 4 objects: X1, X2, X3 and X4, where X1 is a condition with X2 and X3 as its children then we will have 2 paths that start in X1 and end in X4.
Path 1: X1->X2->X4
Path 2: X1->X3->X4

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't show what format the data is after you parse, I'm going to guess :) Here's how I would store the parsed data in ruby objects (using new-style hash key syntax for clarity):

```
[ {yes: 2, no: 3},
  {yes: 4},
  {yes: 4},
  {yes: -1} ]
```

Then, tree-traversal can be done recursively. As long as your arrays aren't several thousands of elements long, this will work fine.

```
def tree(object_number, list)
  if object_number == list.size
    [[object_number]]
  else
    list[object_number-1].values.map { |obj_num|
      tree(obj_num,list)
    }.inject{|a,b| a+b}.map{|l| [object_number] + l}
  end
end
```

Now you call the function:

```
tree(1,data)
  => [[1, 2, 4], [1, 3, 4]]
data = [ {yes: 2, no: 3}, {yes: 4, no:5}, {yes:5, no:4}, {yes:5}, {yes: -1} ]
tree(1,data)
  => [[1, 2, 4, 5], [1, 2, 5], [1, 3, 5], [1, 3, 4, 5]]
```

***How it works:*** The easiest way to build this list is backwards, since we only know the number of paths once we have gotten to the end of all of them. So this code follows the references all the way to the end, and when it gets to the last object, it returns it as a single-element two dimensional array.

```
tree(5,list)
  => [[5]]
```

at each level of recursion, it takes the results of it's recursion call (returned as a list of lists) and prepends it's own object number to each of the interior lists. So, following back up the tree:

```
tree(4,list) # prepends 4 to tree(5)
  => [[4,5]]
tree(3,list) # prepends 3 to tree(4) and tree(5)
  => [[3,4,5],[3,5]]
tree(2,list) # prepends 2 to tree(4) and tree(5)
  => [[2,4,5],[2,5]]
tree(1,list) # prepends 1 to tree(2) and tree(3)
  => [[1, 2, 4, 5], [1, 2, 5], [1, 3, 5], [1, 3, 4, 5]]
```

If the lists might be long enough to overflow your stack, it is always possible to do this without recursion. Recursion is just the simplest way for this particular problem.